Cannot Soft Delete Related Record After Deleting Parents on Laravel 10
I'm using Laravel 10 and I'm having trobule soft delete a child record after deleting parent record. I try using booted in model to delete related record but is not working.
This is the model code:
Planning.php
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
    
    class Planning extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        use SoftDeletes;
    
       protected static function booted(): void
        {
            static::deleted(function ($planning) {
                $planning->planningDetail()->delete();
            });
        }
    
       public function planningDetail(){
            return $this->hasMany(PlanningDetail::class, 'planning_id', 'id');
        }
    }

PlanningDetail.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\UserRecords;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class PlanningDetail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;
    use UserRecords;

   protected static function booted(): void
    {
        static::deleted(function ($planningDetail) {
            $planningDetail->orderRecord()->delete();
        });
    }

   public function orderRecord()
     {
       return $this->hasOne(OrderRecord::class, 'planning_detail_id', 'id');
     }
}

OrderRecord.php

class OrderRecord extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;


    public function planningDetail()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PlanningDetail::class, 'planning_detail_id', 'id');
    }


so I have 3 model here. planning and orderRecord are related to planning_detail where planning has many of planning_detail and orderRecord has one of planning_detail. So I try the soft delete planning which in booted it will deleted that related record with planning which is planning_detail, it did soft delete planning_detail which work as expected.
After deleted planning_detail, In model planning_detail will delete orderRecord after planning_detail is deleted. which in booted if planning_detail delete it will delete order Record but for some reason the booted not working. It just wont deleted the related data which is orderRecord. but i'm able to delete order record itself succesfuly but if i delete the planning one which will delete detail and detail will delete order record. is just not working.
Can someone help me with this.
Thank you.

The order record is not deleted because on the booted Planning, the PlanningDetail is deleted via mass delete statement, so the deleted event on the PlanningDetail will not be dispatched.
You must delete PlanningDetail model individually if you want to dispatch its deleted event. You can do that by modifying the deleted event on the Planning model
static::deleted(function ($planning) {
    $details = $planning->planningDetail;

    foreach ($details as $detail) {
        $detail->delete();
    }
});

or you can use destroy function
static::deleted(function ($planning) {
    $detailsId = $planning->planningDetail()->pluck('id');

    PlanningDetail::destroy($detailsId);
});

Reference: Deleting Models

your second example seems inefficient since it's loading all details twice, at least use $planning->planningDetail()->pluck('id')

another option: $planning->planningDetail->each->delete()
